# Create new row in specific sheet of the excel document VS C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I know that this problem may be addressed in another asked question, is not cause I lost 2 days trying them all.
Lets start the topic:
-I have an desktop app made in Visual Studio Express 2017, C# code used.
-I take 3 variables that I want to store in an excel document that has multiple sheets: Overtime nr. of hours, Day, comment.
Every sheet belongs to an individual that is based on pc username.

```
string datforOV = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();                              //data string
            double hours = decimal.ToDouble(numericUpDown1.Value) + decimal.ToDouble(numericUpDown2.Value) * 0.1;   //number of hours
            string box = richTextBox1.Text;                                                                         //content of text box

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlsht = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet();           
            string path = @"Z\OLP.xlsx";
            xlsht = xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(path).Worksheets[Environment.UserName];
```

I need to add a new row, in the sheet named already after the Username, and fill the first column with nr of hours, second column with the day, and the next one with the comment.
Please help me cause I started losing my minds. Thank in advance.

Comment: this code is included in the function of the button "SEND".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code to add a new row to your named sheet excel.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string datforOV = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();                              //data string
        double hours = decimal.ToDouble(numericUpDown1.Value) + decimal.ToDouble(numericUpDown2.Value) * 0.1;   //number of hours
        string box = richTextBox1.Text;                                                                         //content of text box

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        string path = @"E:\1.xlsx";
        Excel.Workbook workbook = xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Excel.Worksheet xlsht =workbook.Worksheets[Environment.UserName];
        Excel.Range range = xlsht.UsedRange;
        int rowcount = range.Rows.Count;
        Excel.Range next= (Excel.Range)xlsht.Rows[rowcount+1];
        next.Insert();                                     //Another method to add new row
        xlsht.Cells[rowcount + 1, 1] = datforOV;
        xlsht.Cells[rowcount + 1, 2] = hours;
        xlsht.Cells[rowcount + 1, 3] = box;
        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close();
        xlApp.Quit();
        MessageBox.Show("sucess");


    }
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Is getting me out of the trouble. The single thing.. is working only if the sheet is empty, so if i push the button again to add new data, is getting exception error:"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Microsoft Excel can't insert new cells because it would push non-empty cells off the end of the worksheet. These cells might appear empty but have blank values, some formatting, or a formula. Delete enough rows or columns to make room for what you want to insert and then try again.'
"

Comment: @Akatori, based on my test, I reproduced your problem. Therefore, I modified my code for it. Now I changed it  to another way to add new row. Now. you can check if it works for you.

Comment: Man, you are a blessing! It works like a charm.

Comment: @Akatori, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark the reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: Do you know how can I handle the situation when multiple users add data to excel file using the app at the same time?

Comment: You can ask a new question about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561793/c-sharp-how-to-handle-the-situation-when-are-multiple-users-of-an-aplication-tha